# Código autoincrementable MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy intentando realizar un Trigger para que al momento de insertar algo me genere un código automático, por ejemplo tengo estas 3 tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La ultima table es donde quiero que se genere el código, lo que quiero hacer es que al ingresar un dato elijo zona 1, sector 1, quiero que el código que se genere quede en este formato 01-01-001 y que el ultimo campo sea el que se vaya incrementando, si ingreso zona 2, sector 2 entonces que el código me lo guarde así 02-02-001 y así

he realizado este trigger

```
delimiter $
create trigger Generar_codigo before insert on cda for each row
begin
    declare siguiente_codigo int;
   set siguiente_codigo = (Select ifnull(max(convert(substring(codigo_cda, 3), signed integer)), 0) from cda) + 1;
   set new.Codigo = concat(( select z.codigo_zona from zona as z inner join sector as s on s.codigo_sector=z.codigo_zona ),'-',( select s.codigo_sector from zona as z inner join sector as s on s.codigo_sector=z.codigo_zona ),'-',LPAD( siguiente_codigo, 3, '0'));
end $
```

sin embargo no me funciona, solicitaria de su ayuda ya que es la primera vez que lo hago y no tengo muy claro de como hacerlo

Comment: correcto eso solo es la parte de MySQL